# Decomposition of a real function

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I want to find a textbook or paper which has a proof for the following statement:

Let $F: \mathbb{R}_+ \to \mathbb{R}$ be a function. Prove that $F(0) \geq 0$ if and only if $F$ can be written in the form
\begin{equation}
F(x) = f(x) - xg(x),
\end{equation} 
where $f, g$ are functions satisfying $f(x), g(x) \geq 0$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}_+$. Here, $\mathbb{R}_+$ stands for the set of nonnegative real numbers.

Clearly, The statement if 
\begin{equation}
F(x) = f(x) - xg(x),
\end{equation} 
then $F(0) \geq 0$ is obvious but I have not seen the remaining part.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x)=\max \{F(x),0\}$ and $g(x)=\frac  {f(x)-F(x)} x$ for  all $x>0$, $f(0)=F(0),g(0)=0$.

Then $f(x)\geq 0, g(x) \geq 0$  and $F(x)=f(x)-xg(x)$ for  all $x \geq 0$.